# Can I use different log files for FortiGate rules?

Tags: log-files, fortigate

Fortigate firewalls use different log files per type and device. [Here is the log file name format](https://help.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/54/Content/FortiOS/fortigate-logging-reporting-54/logs.htm):

```
    <logtype> - <logdevice> - <date> T <time> . <id>.log
```

For example: `AntiVirusLog-disk-2012-09-13T11_07_57.922495.log`

Is there a way to specify a log file per rule or rules group? Ideally, I would like a separate log file for a group of rules with a given minimal priority level.